# Remove saved network that the app has configured

Tags: java, android, react-native, networking, android-11

*Keep in mind this is for Android 11. A react native application using native bridging.*

Example: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-save-network-passpoint-config

I have the above example working where I pass my passpoint configuration and it adds it to the devices saved network list.

How can I now;

1. Check if the created configuration exists
2. Remove the created configuration

Why I ask?

- It is not part of the WifiSuggestions API so cannot use removeSuggestion()
- Cannot use wifiManager.removeNetwork() since it has been deprecated in API 29 (Android 10)
- Cannot use wifiManager.removePasspointConfiguration as that also has been deprecated in API 29.

I want to be able to add a passpoint configuration, check if it exists and remove it.

**Add Configuration:**

```
      --- Passpoint Configuration created above this code ---
      final WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion1 = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                .setPasspointConfig(passpointConfiguration)
                .build();

        final List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion>();
        suggestionsList.add(suggestion1);
        final WifiManager wifiManager1 = (WifiManager) reactContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        final int status = wifiManager1.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);

        if (status != WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
            // Error handling
            successCallback.invoke(false);
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
            successCallback.invoke(true);
        }
```

**OnActivityResult:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            System.out.println("RESULT OK");          
            // network succesfully added - User pressed Save
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("RESULT CANCELLED");
            // failed attempt of adding network to system - User pressed Cancel
        }
    }
}
```